# What could be the cause of Erratic Heap Usage by a Spring Boot Micro-service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring-admin to monitor my spring micro-services and I found that one of them has a very weird and erratic heap usage graph.

[Erratic Heap Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0xFb.png)

For comparison, here is what I would call "normal" heap usage, with the garbage collection happening at clear even intervals and no extreme volatility like the previous graph.

[Normal Heap Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhinV.png)

Both applications have roughly the same amount of traffic (extremely low) since they are both still in development (maybe 10-20 requests per hour), so load should not be the cause here. What could be happening to create an unusual graph like that?

I tried checking if the application has any leaks or anything but everything checks out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found the culprit behind the weirdness of the graph and honestly its a silly mistake.

I have my spring applications running in a Kubernetes cluster. All of my spring applications have 1 instance, except the one shown in the erratic graph example. Essentially what was happening is spring admin's requests for health data for my application was getting load balanced between mulitple instances in the Kubernetes cluster, causing this very erratic graph.

Hopefully this helps anyone who encounters this silly mistake.